# how to sum data array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, object

i have data from json this data json

```
var someObject = {
 "exam": 
 [
   {
     "re": [[{"result": "3"}],[{"result": "1"}],[{"result": "2"}]]
   },
   {
     "re": [[{"result": "4"}],[{"result": "4"}],[{"result": "4"}]]
   }
   ,
   {
     "re": [[{"result": "2"}],[{"result": "1"}],[{"result": "3"}]]
   }
 ]
};
```

and the problem is how to sum the result?

and I've tried in code like this

```
for (var i = 0; i<someObject.exam.length; i++){
    for (var y = 0; y < someObject.exam[i].re.length; y++){

         $scope.RESS = parseInt(someObject.exam[i].re[y][0].result) +
                       parseInt(someObject.exam[i].re[y][0].result) 
  }
}
```

why the results not same like

```
 3 + 4 + 2; // 9
 1 + 4 + 1; // 6
 2 + 4 + 3; // 9
```

this xample from plunk [xamplle](https://plnkr.co/edit/FSNgZ3EmA4W1XAR1Tcm1?p=preview)

I've spent 2 days for something like this, and now I'm tired help me pleasse

Comment: you want the output as above?

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes how, can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you should calculate it:

```
someObject.exam[0].re.forEach(function(o, i) {
  results.push(parseInt(someObject.exam[0].re[i][0].result) + parseInt(someObject.exam[1].re[i][0].result) + parseInt(someObject.exam[2].re[i][0].result));
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var someObject = {
  "exam": [{
      "re": [
        [{
          "result": "3"
        }],
        [{
          "result": "1"
        }],
        [{
          "result": "2"
        }]
      ]
    },
    {
      "re": [
        [{
          "result": "4"
        }],
        [{
          "result": "4"
        }],
        [{
          "result": "4"
        }]
      ]
    },
    {
      "re": [
        [{
          "result": "2"
        }],
        [{
          "result": "1"
        }],
        [{
          "result": "3"
        }]
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var results = [];

someObject.exam[0].re.forEach(function(o, i) {
  results.push(parseInt(someObject.exam[0].re[i][0].result) + parseInt(someObject.exam[1].re[i][0].result) + parseInt(someObject.exam[2].re[i][0].result));
});
console.log(results);
```

Comment: what the hell is this man, you know 2 days i'm stuck with this code and you finish it in a few minutes, niceeee you save my day, I really thanks to you

Comment: @AdriyanaPutraPratama Hhhhh you are welcome, It just needs some practice and you will be able to perform better :)